# When I make a new activity. The data is not getting displayed properly

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I am very new to android and was trying my hand on it by making a form. I got most of the stuff right except for the part that the data I was entering into my form isn't getting displayed correctly. Here is the code, any help would be appreciated.

MYACTIVITY.JAVA :

```
package com.example.win81.myfirstapp.activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.win81.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity;
import com.example.win81.myfirstapp.R;
import com.example.win81.myfirstapp.interfaces.IConstants;

public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements IConstants {
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.win81.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";

EditText editText1;
EditText editText2;
EditText editText3;
EditText editText4;
EditText editText5;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    editText4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    editText5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String name = intent.getStringExtra("key");
    Button reset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reset);


    reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    editText1.setText("");
                    editText2.setText("");
                    editText3.setText("");
                    editText4.setText("");
                    editText5.setText("");
                }
            });
        }
    });
}


public void sendMessage(View view) {
    // Do something in response to button
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);

    String message = editText1.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(KEY_NAME, message);

    String message1 = editText2.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(KEY_EMAIL, message1);
    String message2 = editText3.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(KEY_PHONE, message2);
    String message3 = editText4.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(KEY_ADDRESS, message3);
    String message4 = editText5.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(KEY_PASS, message4);

    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

ACTIVITY_MY.Xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:background="#006699"><![CDATA[
  tools:context="com.example.win81.myfirstapp.activity.MyActivity">





 ]]>

 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="NAME : "
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView3" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:maxLength="30"
    android:maxHeight="15dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText3" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Email : "
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="61dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:maxLength="50"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Phone : "
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:maxLength="10"
    android:phoneNumber="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView4" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Address : "
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:maxLength="200"
    android:maxLines="3"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView5" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Password : "
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText5"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText4"
    android:maxLength="20"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:password="true"
    android:singleLine="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="SUBMIT"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:onClick="sendMessage"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText5"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView2" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="CLEAR ALL"
    android:id="@+id/reset"
    android:textColor="#a43030"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textClock"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textClock" />

<TextClock
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textClock"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

DISPLAYMESSAGEACTIVITY.JAVA

```
package com.example.win81.myfirstapp;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


import com.example.win81.myfirstapp.activity.MyActivity;
import com.example.win81.myfirstapp.interfaces.IConstants;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements IConstants{


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MyActivity.KEY_NAME);
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);
    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.content);
    layout.addView(textView);



    Intent intent1 = getIntent();
    String message1 = intent1.getStringExtra(MyActivity.KEY_EMAIL);
    TextView textView1 = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(20);
    textView1.setText(message1);

    layout.addView(textView1);


    Intent intent2 = getIntent();
    String message2 = intent2.getStringExtra(KEY_PHONE);
    TextView textView2 = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(10);
    textView2.setText(message2);

    layout.addView(textView2);


    Intent intent3 = getIntent();
    String message3 = intent3.getStringExtra(KEY_ADDRESS);
    TextView textView3 = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView3.setText(message3);
    layout.addView(textView3);


    Intent intent4 = getIntent();
    String message4 = intent4.getStringExtra(KEY_PASS);
    TextView textView4 = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView4.setText(message4);
    layout.addView(textView4);




}
```

}

ACTIVITY_DISPLAY_MESSAGE.Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:id="@+id/content"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="#006699"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
 tools:context="com.example.win81.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="NAME : "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:maxHeight="15dp"
        android:maxLength="30"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_marginTop="61dp"
    android:text="Email : "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:maxLength="50"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/email"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Address"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/Address" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/phone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Phone : "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/email"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:maxLength="10"
    android:phoneNumber="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_above="@+id/Address"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textClock"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textClock" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Address"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Address : "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_below="@+id/phone"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="49dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:maxLength="200"
    android:maxLines="3"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_above="@+id/password"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/reset"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/reset" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Password : "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Address"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="sendMessage"
    android:text="SUBMIT"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textClock"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/password"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/password"
    android:layout_marginBottom="31dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/reset"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="CLEAR ALL"
    android:textColor="#a43030"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textClock"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textClock" />

<TextClock
    android:id="@+id/textClock"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:maxLength="20"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:password="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/password"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2" />
```

Comment: provide details for what is not displayed correctly

Comment: On the second activity page. All the fields get displayed on top of each other. The name,email,phone number I enter all get displayed on top of each other.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are creating new TextViews in your DisplayMessageActivity. Instead you should use the TextViews added in activity_display_message.xml layout.

Use findViewById to get reference of your views like you did in 1st Activity.

Comment: Thank you Sir. It was great help. Very stupid of me to make such an error. Thanks again. :)

Comment: I need 15 reputation first. It's not letting me do it for now. I won't forget.

Comment: Hey! I'm also new to stackoverflow. How about we help increase each other's repo once we get to 15? :)